# Is it possible to use the FontAwesome search API to return only an icon whose ID matches my query exactly?

Tags: graphql, font-awesome

I can search for Font Awesome icons which match the string "donut" like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \-d '{ "query": "{search(version: \"6.0.0\", query: \"donut\", first: 5) { id, label }}" }' \https://api.fontawesome.com
```

But is there a query I can make which, rather than doing this sort of fuzzy matching, will just return the single icon whose id is "donut"?

(Yes I could simply always use the first result the fuzzy search returns, but I'm not sure that's 100% guaranteed to be the one where the result id exactly matches the string I input.)

Font Awesome docs: https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/graphql/get-started

Comment: Doesn't look like it, but a workaround I found is to query the ID with no `first` value and then just find the specific icon I need in the fuzzy search. i.e. `json?.data?.search.find(icon => icon?.id === 'image');` returns the icon result for `fa-image`.